# Is it compulsory to make app compatible with iOS8 while submitting to Apple?

Tags: ios8

I am near to completing my app within 1-2 days, but iOS 8 has now been released. Is it compulsory to make my app compatible with iOS8? Will Apple reject it otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

By the way Here is the recent announcement from apple regarding this..

> Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included in Xcode 6 or later. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a

Comment: The real question (I have) is if existing apps can still be updated without supporting 64 bit. If not, I have a lot of work to do.

Answer (score 1):

right now it is not compulsory, use Xcode 5.1.1 if you want to support iOS7 for time been and submit the app..but users might face issues if they are using iOS8 on their devices.